# Can't change property of css in react

Tags: css, reactjs, properties

I am programming  a website and I want to validate the input fields. In my little example I want to have a valid state if the input field is empty. When the user types any characters in this input field the backround color should be red. But how can I change the state of the input field in invalid?

Here is my react code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  function test(e) {
    if (e.target.value != "") {
      console.log("change state of input field");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={test} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS

```
form input[type="text"]:valid {
  background-color: green;
}
form input[type="text"]:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I searched on the internet but I found only solutions, where variables were defined and getting changed by onChange functions. I have never seen an example where a variable is changed and ensures that the intended css line is also executed. In this case invalid should be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply css class based on your validation state variable.

Css

```
.valid {
  color: green;
  border-color: green;
  height: 40px;
}
.invalid {
  color: red;
  border-color: red;
  height: 40px;
}
```

React

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [validate, setValidate] = useState(false);

function test(e) {
    if (e.target.value != "") {
      //control validate here
    }
    }

  return (
    <div>
      <input className={validate ? 'valid' : 'invalid'} />
      <button
        className={validate ? 'valid' : 'invalid'}
        onClick={() => setValidate((prev) => !prev)}
      >
        Validate
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rhpd6n